# HYBRIS Flexible Query to get all the products from Order Model

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

My requirement is to get the list of customers who have ordered an old product.
Here for the old product, we are using an attribute "endproduct".
I am able to get all the customers who have placed orders. BUT I don't know how to create a query to get products from Order Model.

I have run this query :

```
SELECT distinct {c:uid},{aeo:product} from 
{customer as c JOIN order as o on {c:pk}={o:user}JOIN AbstractOrder as ao on {o:pk}={ao:pk} JOIN AbstractOrderEntry as aeo on {ao:pk}={aeo:pk}}
```

Because AbstractOrderEntryModel has a product attribute.

Comment: Is `endproduct` attribute of productModel or AbstractOrderEntryModel ?

Comment: endproduct is attribute of productModel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like

```
SELECT
distinct {u:uid},{p:name}
FROM { Order AS o JOIN OrderEntry AS oe ON {o.pk} = {oe.order} JOIN Product AS p ON {p.pk} = {oe.product} and {p.endproduct} = '1' JOIN User AS u ON {o.user} = {u.pk}}
```

Change `endproduct` condition as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks, It worked. OrderEntryModel extends AbstractOrderEntry which served the purpose.I am able to keep further conditions as per my requiremnet.

Answer (score 1):

Try below query, it should give expected results.

```
select {c.uid},{p.code}
from {Customer as c}, {Order as o}, {Product as p}, {AbstractOrderEntry as ao}
where {o.user} = {c.pk} and {o.pk} = {ao.order} and {ao.product} = {p.pk}
```